Dataframe replace columns and save to new df
I loaded in a .dat file to a pandas dataframe. Two of the columns are mean and error. I used the values in these two columns to create a randomized value for mean. I want to replace the mean column in the dataframe with the new values for mean. However I want to continuously do this and create new dataframes as I go because every dataframe needs to be saved back to a file and used in a simulation.
df = pd.read_table('file.dat', skiprows=9, sep="\s+", usecols=[0,1,2,3,4], names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])

N = 10
r = np.random.normal(df['col3'], abs(df['col4']), (N, len(df)))

for i in r:
    df['col3'] = r[i]
    df.copy() = df[i]{i} #Wanted to copy what I just made and save it to a new named dataframe, not sure how to convert the dataframe back to a .dat file either


If your problem is just how to create new file names and save each dataframe you can do:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

out_folder = r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/hello/"
df = pd.read_csv(r"/home/bera/GIS/Kod/Pandas/Seaborn_datasets/car_crashes.csv")

n = 5 #Do something n times
for x in range(5): 
    tempdf = df.copy() #Copy the original dataframe
    new_values = np.random.randint(0,100, size=df.shape[0]) #Create some random values
    tempdf[f"column_{x}"] = new_values #Store them in a column
    tempdf.to_csv(os.path.join(out_folder, f"data_iteration_{x}.csv")) #Save the dataframe


